# Twitter streaming script is throwing a keyerror on location field of the tweet

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I have as of now written a Python script to stream tweets and I have made use of the tweepy module to do so. After streaming for around 3 minutes for tweets, I dump these tweets into a .json file. I populate these tweets (I try to) into a pandas dataframe for **location** and **text** fields of the tweet. The text field of the tweet gets populated **but not for every tweet** (problem 1) in the .json file and as far as the location field is concerned a **keyerror** (problem 2) is thrown. May I know what exactly is going wrong.

**twitter_stream_dump.py**

```
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
import re

#tweepy based modules
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


#initializing authentication credentials
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_key = ''
access_secret = ''

#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener) :
    def __init__(self,time_limit) :
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.saveFile = open('requests.json','a')
        super(StdOutListener,self).__init__()

    def on_data(self, data) :
        if ((time.time() - self.start_time) < self.limit) :
            self.saveFile.write(data)
            self.saveFile.write('\n')
            return True
        else :
            self.saveFile.close()
            return False

    def on_error(self, status) :
        print(status)

def getwords(string) :
    return re.findall(r"[\w'#]+|[.,!?;]",string)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)

    time_limit = input("Enter the time limit in minutes : ")
    time_limit *= 60

    stream = Stream(auth,listener = StdOutListener(time_limit))
    string = raw_input("Enter the list of keywords/hashtags to be compared : ")

    keyword_list = getwords(string)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track = keyword_list)

    tweets_data_path = 'requests.json'

    tweets_data = []
    tweet_list = []

    tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

    for line in tweets_file :
        try :
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweet_list.append(tweet)
        except :
            continue

    num_tweets_collected = len(tweet_list)

    #Creates a data frame structure
    tweet_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    text_dump = open('text_dump.txt', 'w')


    #Populating the location field of the data frame

    #tweet_dataframe['location'] = map(lambda tweet : tweet['location'], tweet_list)

    tweet_dataframe['text'] = map(lambda tweet : tweet['text'], tweet_list)
    print(tweet_dataframe['text'])
```

Errors :

```
abhijeet-mohanty-2:Desktop SubrataMohanty$ python twitter_stream_dump.py 
Enter the time limit in minutes : 3
Enter the list of keywords/hashtags to be compared : python ruby scala
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_stream_dump.py", line 81, in <module>
    tweet_dataframe['location'] = map(lambda tweet : tweet['location'], tweet_list)
  File "twitter_stream_dump.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    tweet_dataframe['location'] = map(lambda tweet : tweet['location'], tweet_list)
KeyError: 'location'
```

**requests.json** (My .json file) 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1p05OszaBkXLWFsQ2VmeWVjbDQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` field is a user-defined value and will sometimes not be present. 
 That's why you're getting the `KeyError`.

Note that `location` is part of the ["user profile" metadata](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) that comes with a tweet.  It's intended to describe a user's location (like their hometown), and *not the geotagged location* of a given tweet.

In case you're interested in geotags, first check a tweeet to see if the `geo_enabled` field is `true`.  If so, the `geo`, `coordinates`, and `place` fields may contain geotagged information.

As for missing `text` entries, I don't see the same issue when using the data you provided.  It's possible the issue was caused by your `try`/`except` clause when reading in lines of data.  Consider this approach:

```
for i, line in enumerate(tweets_file):
    if line.rstrip():
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweet_list.append(tweet)

num_tweets_collected = len(tweet_list)

texts = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweet_list]
tweet_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns=['text'])
```

Sample output:

```
print(tweet_dataframe.head())
#                                                 text
# 0     Tweets and python BFF &lt;3 15121629.976126991
# 1  RT @zeroSteiner: Can now write more post modul...
# 2          •ruby• #MtvInstagLSelena #MtvColabTaylors
# 3  Ruby Necklace  July Birthstone Jewelry  Rosary...
# 4  @ossia I didn't see any such thing as Python. ...
```

A few quick summary stats show that no lines are missing, and no entries are `null`:

```
print("N tweets: {}".format(num_tweets_collected))
# N tweets: 286

print("N rows in dataframe: {}".format(tweet_dataframe.shape[0]))
# N rows in dataframe: 286

null_count = tweet_dataframe.text.isnull().sum()
print("Tweets with no text field extracted: {}".format(null_count))
# Tweets with no text field extracted: 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help but is there still a way to collect the location field from the tweet. The reason for this is that I wish to normalize every location entry into a standardized value.

Comment: The short answer is no.  More specifically, it depends on whether you actually want the `location` field, which is part of a user profile and not related to a specific tweet, or whether you want a tweet's geolocation. If a user hasn't turned on geotagging for a tweet, then you will not be able to get geolocation data.  If a user hasn't filled out the `location` field in the personal profile section, you will not be able to get that field, either.  FWIW, only a very small percentage (1-2%) of all tweets are geotagged.